# Are booleans objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, boolean

Are booleans objects in JavaScript? Is it true that "everything is an object" in JavaScript?

Comment: http://www.diveintojavascript.com/core-javascript-reference/the-boolean-object

Comment: For extensive coverage of the Javascript language consult [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Primitives](http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.2) are not objects, everything else ([any standard object](http://es5.github.com/#x15-toc)) is an object. However, most primitives (all apart from `undefined` and `null`) have an object counterpart.

So

```
var a = false;
```

is not an object, but

```
var b = new Boolean(false);
```

is.

Since two objects are only equal if they refer to one and the same object, using the object version of primitives should better be avoided:

```
a === false; // is true
b === false // is false   <- this is a problem
```

Or especially with boolean objects, using them with any boolean operators will create unexpected results. An object reference always evaluates to `true`, so the outcome of using `b` would be:

```
// remember
// a is the primitive value false
// b is a boolean object with value false

// NOT
!a // true
// but
!b // false

// AND
a && true // false
// but
b && true // true
```

There is no real advantage of using these object versions anyway, since JavaScript is [autoboxing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoboxing#Autoboxing) primitives when you try to call methods on them. That's why calls like:

```
var s = "HI THERE!".toLowerCase();
s = s.substring(0,2);
```

are possible.

Comment: However, you virtually never want object-wrapped primitives.

Comment: there is a purpose (although not very useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/856330/908879) _"...is to convert non boolean objects into a boolean"_

Comment: @ajax333221: True, you could indeed use it for type conversion. In this case, you could also use double negation though, e.g. `!!"someString"`. Also it is important to note that there is a difference between calling `Boolean` (and any other of these functions) as function or as constructor. As function they all(?) return primitive values.

Comment: not conformed with already an accepted answer and +7 votes, he keeps doing awesome edits. If everyone were like Felix Fling, there would probably be world peace and we will likely find cure to most of incurable diseases of today

Comment: @ajax333221: Thanks for the compliment :)

Answer (score 1):

Booleans, numbers and strings are object-like types - they have methods, but they are immutable.